# How do i add models from my flutter app model class to my laravel app model class?

Tags: laravel, database, flutter, model

Hello guys i have a flutter app that was handed over to me by a previous developer, the backend is in laravel, me being not so good at laravel i am having difficulties adding all of my User models in my flutter app to my laravel app models.

After adding this, i want these fields to reflect on my database and be able to retrieve the values in my flutter app in return.

Specifically, i want to add roles to users, and this Role is a list of either salon owner or admin.

I will give my Flutter User model :

```
class User extends Model {
  String name;
  String email;
  String password;
  Media avatar;
  String apiToken;
  String deviceToken;
  String phoneNumber;
  bool verifiedPhone;
  String verificationId;
  String address;
  String bio;
  List<Role> roles;

  bool auth;

  User(
      {this.name,
      this.email,
      this.password,
      this.apiToken,
      this.deviceToken,
      this.phoneNumber,
      this.verifiedPhone,
      this.verificationId,
      this.address,
      this.bio,
      this.avatar,
      this.roles});

  User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = stringFromJson(json, 'name');
    email = stringFromJson(json, 'email');
    apiToken = stringFromJson(json, 'api_token');
    deviceToken = stringFromJson(json, 'device_token');
    phoneNumber = stringFromJson(json, 'phone_number');
    verifiedPhone = boolFromJson(json, 'phone_verified_at');
    avatar = mediaFromJson(json, 'avatar');
    auth = boolFromJson(json, 'auth');
    roles = listFromJson(json, 'roles', (v) => Role.fromJson(v));
    try {
      address = json['custom_fields']['address']['view'];
    } catch (e) {
      address = stringFromJson(json, 'address');
    }
    try {
      bio = json['custom_fields']['bio']['view'];
    } catch (e) {
      bio = stringFromJson(json, 'bio');
    }
    super.fromJson(json);
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['name'] = this.name;
    data['email'] = this.email;
    if (password != null && password != '') {
      data['password'] = this.password;
    }
    data['api_token'] = this.apiToken;
    if (deviceToken != null) {
      data["device_token"] = deviceToken;
    }
    data["phone_number"] = phoneNumber;
    if (verifiedPhone != null && verifiedPhone) {
      data["phone_verified_at"] = DateTime.now().toLocal().toString();
    }
    data["address"] = address;
    data["bio"] = bio;
    if (this.avatar != null && Uuid.isUuid(avatar.id)) {
      data['avatar'] = this.avatar.id;
    }
    if (avatar != null) {
      data["media"] = [avatar.toJson()];
    }
    data['auth'] = this.auth;
    if (roles != null) {
      data['roles'] = this.roles.map((e) => e.toJson()).toList();
    }
    return data;
  }

  Map toRestrictMap() {
    var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    map["id"] = id;
    map["email"] = email;
    map["name"] = name;
    map["thumb"] = avatar.thumb;
    map["device_token"] = deviceToken;
    return map;
  }

  PhoneNumber getPhoneNumber() {
    if (this.phoneNumber != null) {
      this.phoneNumber = this.phoneNumber.replaceAll(' ', '');
      String dialCode1 = this.phoneNumber.substring(1, 2);
      String dialCode2 = this.phoneNumber.substring(1, 3);
      String dialCode3 = this.phoneNumber.substring(1, 4);
      for (int i = 0; i < countries.length; i++) {
        if (countries[i].dialCode == dialCode1) {
          return new PhoneNumber(
              countryISOCode: countries[i].code,
              countryCode: dialCode1,
              number: this.phoneNumber.substring(2));
        } else if (countries[i].dialCode == dialCode2) {
          return new PhoneNumber(
              countryISOCode: countries[i].code,
              countryCode: dialCode2,
              number: this.phoneNumber.substring(3));
        } else if (countries[i].dialCode == dialCode3) {
          return new PhoneNumber(
              countryISOCode: countries[i].code,
              countryCode: dialCode3,
              number: this.phoneNumber.substring(4));
        }
      }
    }
    return new PhoneNumber(
        countryISOCode:
            Get.find<SettingsService>().setting.value.defaultCountryCode,
        countryCode: '1',
        number: '');
  }

  bool get isAdmin =>
      (this.roles?.where((element) => element.name == 'admin')?.length ?? 0) >
      0;

  bool get isSalonOwner =>
      (this
              .roles
              ?.where((element) =>
                  element.name == 'salon owner' || element.name == 'admin')
              ?.length ??
          0) >
      0;

  bool get isCustomer =>
      (this.roles?.where((element) => element.isdDefault)?.length ?? 0) > 0;

  @override
  bool operator ==(Object other) =>
      super == other &&
      other is User &&
      runtimeType == other.runtimeType &&
      name == other.name &&
      email == other.email &&
      password == other.password &&
      avatar == other.avatar &&
      apiToken == other.apiToken &&
      deviceToken == other.deviceToken &&
      phoneNumber == other.phoneNumber &&
      verifiedPhone == other.verifiedPhone &&
      verificationId == other.verificationId &&
      address == other.address &&
      bio == other.bio &&
      roles == other.roles &&
      auth == other.auth;

  @override
  int get hashCode =>
      super.hashCode ^
      name.hashCode ^
      email.hashCode ^
      password.hashCode ^
      avatar.hashCode ^
      apiToken.hashCode ^
      deviceToken.hashCode ^
      phoneNumber.hashCode ^
      verifiedPhone.hashCode ^
      verificationId.hashCode ^
      address.hashCode ^
      bio.hashCode ^
      roles.hashCode ^
      auth.hashCode;
}
```

This is My User model from my laravel app which gets me more confused when i try to read it:

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements HasMedia
{
    use Notifiable;
    use Billable;
    use HasMediaTrait {
        getFirstMediaUrl as protected getFirstMediaUrlTrait;
    }
    use HasRoles;

    /**
     * Validation rules
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $rules = [
        'name' => 'required|string|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
        'phone_number' => 'required|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required',
    ];

    public $table = 'users';
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'phone_number',
        'phone_verified_at',
        'password',
        'api_token',
        'device_token',
    ];
    /**
     * The attributes that should be casted to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'name' => 'string',
        'email' => 'string',
        'phone_number' => 'string',
        'password' => 'string',
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'phone_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'api_token' => 'string',
        'device_token' => 'string',
        'remember_token' => 'string',
        'roles' => 'string'
    ];
    /**
     * New Attributes
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $appends = [
        'custom_fields',
        'has_media'
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * Route notifications for the FCM channel.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function routeNotificationForFcm(\Illuminate\Notifications\Notification $notification): ?string
    {
        return $this->device_token;
    }

    /**
     * @param Media|null $media
     * @throws InvalidManipulation
     */
    public function registerMediaConversions(\Spatie\MediaLibrary\Models\Media $media = null)
    {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumb')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 200, 200)
            ->sharpen(10);

        $this->addMediaConversion('icon')
            ->fit(Manipulations::FIT_CROP, 100, 100)
            ->sharpen(10);
    }

    /**
     * to generate media url in case of fallback will
     * return the file type icon
     * @param string $conversion
     * @return string url
     */
    public function getFirstMediaUrl($collectionName = 'default', $conversion = '')
    {
        $url = $this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName);
        if ($url) {
            $array = explode('.', $url);
            $extension = strtolower(end($array));
            if (in_array($extension, config('medialibrary.extensions_has_thumb'))) {
                return asset($this->getFirstMediaUrlTrait($collectionName, $conversion));
            } else {
                return asset(config('medialibrary.icons_folder') . '/' . $extension . '.png');
            }
        } else {
            return asset('images/avatar_default.png');
        }
    }

    public function getCustomFieldsAttribute()
    {
        $hasCustomField = in_array(static::class, setting('custom_field_models', []));
        if (!$hasCustomField) {
            return [];
        }
        $array = $this->customFieldsValues()
            ->join('custom_fields', 'custom_fields.id', '=', 'custom_field_values.custom_field_id')
            ->select(['value', 'view', 'name'])
            ->get()->toArray();

        return convertToAssoc($array, 'name');
    }

    public function customFieldsValues(): MorphMany
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Models\CustomFieldValue', 'customizable');
    }

    /**
     * Add Media to api results
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getHasMediaAttribute(): bool
    {
        return $this->hasMedia('avatar');
    }

    /**
     * @return BelongsToMany
     **/
    public function salons(): BelongsToMany
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Salon::class, 'salon_users');
    }

}
```

I have tried adding the line

// 'roles' => 'string' in my laravel app model but i don't think it's okay.

I need help please.

Comment: i think this is not the code for viewing the result try to go on the controllers instead and find the function which return the data, The file you gave is on model which handle for fcm and ORM relationship to models

Comment: @ArbiterChil In my Laravel app, i have the http/controllers, in the controllers folder i have a controller files, also in the controller folder i have an 'api' folder containing api controllers and an 'auth' folder. which of this information would you need?

Comment: which api did you use to get the data find the function on that on the controllers on the auth is this fir register or signin?

Comment: If you mainly work on flutter and seeing this laravel model for the first time you may be confused but please remember that this model is not what you think it is as we need model in `Flutter` to convert JSON strings to `Objects` but in laravel the model is just a class reference for the `database` table In this case `User` model in laravel refers to `users` table which this laravel app is using.

Comment: Also remember you do not need to work on models in case you want to change the table columns in database you need to work on the migrations files in the laravel.